# using vrif hand poser how to make an object on other object unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculus, oculusquest

im new in unity , and im trying to create  a VR project on Oculus using Vrif on unity , so to put u on the project so i have two objects ' Trocar ' and ' Laparascope ' holded by the Vrif Hands like the photo below , i want to put the object in the left hand on the object in the right hand when i run the scene , i want to test it on my laptop befor testing on Oculus Quest 2 , is it possible !
[image]